# How to Create custom google marker using lru cache in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-lru-cache

Hi can anyone give sample code to create a custom google marker using lru cache.I don't know how to reuse the bitmap and clear the cache while exceeds the memory.

Comment: cache? how many unique markers do you want to have?

Comment: it is about 20 unique markers.

Comment: and a marker Bitmap is like 64x64 px or so?

Comment: Image size differs according to device